# Container exits from docker-compose up but I can run it manually

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Well, basically I got this `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:

  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./schemas/mysql.sql:/data/application/init.sql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: 10.5.0.1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: forgottenserver
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
    command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    networks:
      tibia:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5

  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
    networks:
      tibia:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.3

networks:
  tibia:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
          gateway: 10.5.0.1
volumes:
  db_data:
```

and this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04@sha256:bffb6799d706144f263f4b91e1226745ffb5643ea0ea89c2f709208e8d70c999

ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
ENV WD=/home/tibia/server
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN useradd --system --create-home --shell /bin/bash --gid root --groups sudo --uid 1001 tibia

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y tzdata \
    autoconf automake pkg-config build-essential cmake \
    liblua5.1-0-dev libsqlite3-dev libmysqlclient-dev \
    libxml2-dev libgmp3-dev libboost-filesystem-dev \
    libboost-regex-dev libboost-thread-dev

USER tibia
WORKDIR $WD

COPY . .
RUN mv config.lua.dist config.lua && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake .. && \
    make -j$(grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l)

EXPOSE 7171 7172
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

The `Dockerfile` is just building an executable.

The problem is that if I add this to the compose file and try to run all those services, the one that uses the Dockerfile just exits and doesn't restart:

```
# ...
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "7171:7171"
      - "7172:7172"
    networks:
      tibia:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.4
```

But if I run the compose with just the services `db` and `phpmyadmin`, and then run manually my built image from Dockerfile using:

```bash
docker run -itd --network=3777_tibia --ip 10.5.0.4 -p 7171:7171 -p 7172:7172 3777_server
```

Then it works like a charm!!!! Even the network does work.

Some screenshots of my Docker Desktop:
[image: list of containers]
[image: server container logs]

How can I make this missing service work with the docker-compose file?

NEW EDIT:
image of the logs:
[image: logs]

Comment: Have you checked logs of failed container ?

Comment: if you mean in the Docker Desktop logs, there are no logs at all! I just updated the main post with a screenshot of the logs page.

Comment: docker logs -f <container_id> try this command with containerId which is failing to start. It will show you logs.

Comment: even worse... the container with the problem is not even listed when I use docker container ls, and using the ID provided from Docker Desktop UI doesn't work too.

Comment: have you tried "docker ps -a " command ? It will list all containers.

Comment: same issue, no logs at all... updated the main topic with a screenshot of that

Comment: Your Dockerfile shows the image builds an executable, but the container just starts a bash shell. My guess is the docker compose just kills the container as the shell has nothing to interact with, but at the command prompt you can interact with the bash shell and hence it runs there. A container should run a non-interactive program as its main executable.

Comment: @JohnXF what would you suggest doing?

Comment: @JoãoCasarin I presume your image should run the executable you just built? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708771/running-lua-script-in-docker

Comment: I understand that this is the expected command I should run, but shouldn't compose work with a simple bash CMD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dockerfile specifies `bash` as the command to run.

When you run it via the docker-compose file, bash sees that there's no TTY and it exits immediately and the container stops.

When you run it from the command line, you attach a TTY using the `-it` options. Bash then runs interactively and waits for input.

To get your container to run interactively when run from docker-compose, you need to add `stdin_open` and `tty` options, like this

```
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "7171:7171"
      - "7172:7172"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      tibia:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.4
```

Comment: indeed this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Your Dockerfile specifies `bash` as the command to run.  It doesn't actually run the program you built.  Since Compose is oriented towards running multiple long-running service-type containers, it's tricky to interact with an interactive shell as the main container process.  You also don't usually want to start a container, then start the thing the container does; you just want to start the container and have it run the process.

Once you've built the program, set the image's `CMD` to run it.

```bash
CMD ["./the_program"]
```

With a typical C(++) program built using Make, you should be able to `make install` it into `/usr/local` where you can run it without specifying a path explicitly.  You could combine this with a multi-stage build to get a much smaller image without any of the build tools or header files.

Comment: I understand that it is not running the executable I built, however I thought that the container should start with no problems if the CMD was a bash instance

Comment: bash by default will exit if it's run as a background process; if it doesn't have an input and doesn't have a script to run, it just stops.  But you don't want to run bash, you want to run the executable you've built.  (The container on its own isn't especially valuable.)

Comment: ok i get it... now waht still doesn't make sense tho is that when I run the executable I built, the container exits automatically too... I still need to set `stdin_open` and `tty` options to make it work with compose... why is that?